# SVN to GIT migration without TRUNK in repository

Tags: git, svn, github, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I have SVN repository with structure as below:
  - BRANCHES   Holds the code from the vendors repository(software provider code)
  - DEV        Took from BRANCHES and developers use it
  - RC(release candidate) After development code is put to RC for testing
  - TAGS  Code which is released after each build with new functionality

I have been asked to move these type of SVN repositories to GIT

How can I structure the GIT w.r.t SVN?
How to move code from SVN to GIT without TRUNK?
How to set Master/Head/Branches/Tags in GIT comparing to Branches/DEV/RC/Tags

Comment: You may want to investigate the [git svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a clone like this:

```
git svn clone svn://server.domain.org/pathtorepo
```

You will get an unmodified clone of the entire SVN directory structure and history converted to git.

Once in git you can convert directories to branches with;

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ...
```

You can use `git filter-branch --tree-filter` to make smaller file changes.

You can use `.git/info/grafts` and `git filter-branch` to attach branches to the points they split off from other branches.

But merges are more difficult because SVN doesn't have a standard merge marker.

The `git svn` command does have things to interpret "standard layouts" of the svn directory structure, but I don't expect that to be too helpful for you. There are, however, other options you will want to use.

BUT if you really want to do the best job you should probably look at the [Reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/) tool.